# Nuget file with build type set to Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nullreferenceexception, nuget-package

I am building a nuget package and i want it to add a `js` script upon installation on any project.
the `.js` file must have it's build action set to Embedded resource.

I have tried adding a `Install.ps1` script to package with below content :

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$item = $project.projectItems.Item("my_script.js")
$item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = [int]3
```

but it returns error :

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   + $item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = [int]3

i think the error is because the `Install.ps1` script runs before adding package files to solution therefore there is no `my_script.js` so we can't change its build action...

so, how we do it?

is there any way to run script after files being deployed in project ??

**Update**

One more thing that could be the problem is that `my_script.js` is not in the root of `Content` folder. Do I need to address its path when I call :

`$project.projectItems.Item("myfolder/my_script.js")` ?

**Update 2**

Nope! the problem exists even after addressing the folder like above.

Comment: The install.ps1 script is run last. It does not run before the files are added to the project. I would check your PowerShell script in the Package Manager Console to see if it works. Also does your my_script.js file get added to the root of the project?

Comment: Yes! Although it throws that exception, it adds the file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when you want to access a file which is not in the root directory of project, you need to do it like below:(i.e. code used in question)

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$item = $project.ProjectItems.Item("myfolder")
$item2 = $item.ProjectItems.Item("script.js")
$item2.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = [int]3
```

the file is `script.js` within the folder `myfolder`, (full path of file relative to project directory: `myfolder/script.js`)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your .ps1 script and it add the js script file as Embedded resource when installing the NuGet package. Please check your .nuspec file for your package, make sure the **.ps1 is named install.ps1** and **it added into Tools folder**.

The  node in your .nuspec file for your nuget package should be the same as below shows, which has tested successful in my side.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>BuildActionTest</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>AuthorName</authors>
    <owners>OwnerName</owners>
    <description>Test Buid Action</description>
    <releaseNotes>Test Buid Action</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Build Action</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
   <file src="JavaScript1.js" target="Content"/>
   <file src="install.ps1" target="tools"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: My Script is named Install.ps1 , one thing that could be the real problem is that i did not define my files in .nuspec manifest as you did, is it mandatory to name all my files in the manifest? there are too many of them !

Comment: One more thing that could be the problem is that my_script.js is not in the root of Content folder. Do I need to address its path when I call :

`$project.projectItems.Item("myfolder/my_script.js")` ?

Comment: @Amin Nadimi You need not to add the file path into your ps1 file. So you still could get the my_script.js file with “$project.projectItems.Item("myfolder/my_script.js")”. You could add all the files into manifest file with “*”. For example, you could add all js files, you could use <file src="*.js" target="Content"/>.